# Podcast from my server works on iTunes desktop, but not on mobile

Tags: ios, xml, podcast

I have an issue where I'm trying to host a podcast via RSS feed myself, and I'm running into a strange issue.  I validated my RSS feed and all of that, got everything working on iTunes on the desktop just fine.  However, when I go to play that same podcast on my iPhone, I either get a "podcast is temporarily unavailable" error, or nothing at all.  All of the information shows up fine and everything, but nothing will play.  I made sure to check with my hosting service that Byte Range Requests are supported, and enabled.  I don't know what the problem could be.  The RSS looks like this (I edited some personal information out):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

<channel>

<title>Striate Cortex Testing...</title>
<description>This is a test of the Striate Cortex Podcasting System...</description>
<link>http://www.striatecortex.com</link>
<language>en-us</language>
<copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
<lastBuildDate>Tue, 16 Feb 2016 08:55:00 -0500</lastBuildDate>
<pubDate>Tue, 16 Feb 2016 08:55:00 -0500</pubDate>
<docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
<webMaster>EMAIL (NAME)</webMaster>

<itunes:author>Striate Cortex</itunes:author>
    <itunes:subtitle>PODCASTNAME is a show about interviewing other musicians, and talking about what life is like on the road.</itunes:subtitle>
    <itunes:summary>PODCASTNAME is a show about interviewing other musicians, and talking about what life is like on the road.  Something else to make this longer.</itunes:summary>

    <itunes:owner>
           <itunes:name>Striate Cortex</itunes:name>
           <itunes:email>EMAIL</itunes:email>
    </itunes:owner>

<itunes:explicit>Yes</itunes:explicit>

<itunes:image href="http://www.striatecortex.com/podcast.png"/>

<itunes:category text="Music">
</itunes:category>

<atom:link href="http://www.striatecortex.com/test.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />

<item>
<title>Striate Cortex - PodcastName Test # 1</title>
<link>http://www.striatecortex.com/podcast/test</link>
<guid>http://www.striatecortex.com/test.mp3</guid>
<description>This is a description.</description>
<enclosure url="http://www.striatecortex.com/test.mp3" length="29184000" type="audio/mpeg"/>
<category>Podcasts</category>
<pubDate>Tue, 16 Feb 2016 08:55:00 -0500</pubDate>

</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```